# zebra theme in sas doesn't with with noprint

Tags: sas

I am trying to highlight every second row in proc report.

I can do this using a dummy variable (that is either 0 or 1 if the row is even), but when I add `/ noprint` to the define statement for that variable it stops highlighting.

**Code:**

```
/* set up data with dummy variable */
data dummy;
    set     sashelp.class;
    dummy   = mod(_n_, 2);
run;
    
/* displaying the dummy variable */
proc report data = dummy;
    define  dummy / display;
    compute dummy;
        if  dummy eq 1 then call define (_row_, 'style', 'style = [ background = #DFDFDF]');
    endcomp;
run;

/* hiding the dummy variable */
proc report data = dummy;
    define  dummy / noprint;
    compute dummy;
        if  dummy eq 1 then call define (_row_, 'style', 'style = [ background = #DFDFDF]');
    endcomp;
run;
```

**Outputs:**

[image]

Is there a way to keep the highlighting format even when then dummy column isn't displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm an idiot, you can have BOTH `display` and `noprint`, which does the trick:

```
proc report data = dummy;
    define  dummy / display noprint;
    compute dummy;
        if  dummy eq 1 then call define (_row_, 'style', 'style = [ background = #DFDFDF]');
    endcomp;
run;
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: One of the funnest oddities `DISPLAY NOPRINT` always struck me as oxymoronic.

Comment: yeah i didn't think to try it for ages becuase I assumed they were the opposites of each other :P

Answer (score 0):

You can see how PROC REPORT sees your statements with the PROC statement option LIST. When the type is a statistic use a dotted name.

```
COMPUTE  dummy;
if dummy.sum eq 1 then call define(_row_, 'style', 'style = [ background = #DFDFDF]');
ENDCOMP;
```

[image]